# How to create PDF with Text (not image!) from Angular Templates (html -> pdf)

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, pdf-generation

I have been trying these libraries:

-[html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js)

-[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

But they both use html2canvas, which create a picture from a part of your html, and then you can write it to a pdf file.

Is there any other Javascript library out there, which can also create textual pdf with selectable text, and best reuse part of an existing html file (or in my case a part of a template of my Angular Component)?